# Change conda environment of a running ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I have a `ipython` jupyter-notebook open and running on a `conda` environment `env1`.
Is there a way to change the `conda` environment to `env2` of the same running notebook ?

Answer (score 0):

No. At the very least, you will have to restart the kernel in the new environment. And you cannot change conda environments from inside the kernel at all.

Anaconda has a special feature that detects kernelspecs in different environments. If that is enabled in your setup, you should be able to switch the kernelspec to the other environment, which automatically restarts the kernel. Note that ipykernel needs to be installed in the target environment.